# How to set default parameters for solr CoreAdminHandler?

Tags: solr

Since Solr 7.0 version all handlers return JSON format response. I know I can use `<initParams>` to configure default response format for known handlers. Though, I can't seem to apply `<initParams>` configuration to `/admin/cores` requests that are processed by a special handler `CoreAdminHandler` that is not defined in `solrconfig.xml`.
I tried adding `<initParams>` configuration mapping it to path `/admin/cores` but that had no effect.

```
<initParams path="/admin/cores">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

I still get JSON response when I call `/admin/cores?action=status`.
Is it possible to influence response format for `CoreAdminHandler` requests via configuration?

Comment: Does it respect `&wt=xml` in the URL?

Comment: Yes it does but that doesn't work for me. I can't supply additional parameters to admin core `STATUS` call because I have legacy code that I can't change. I'd like to force Solr admin core API to spit out XML responses by default. I can do it for handlers configured in `solrconfig.xml` but couldn't find a way to do it for admin core requests.

Comment: Yes, my point was just that it's useful to confirm that the setting works before trying to change the default value of it :-)